# iPhone app to follow/navigate an imported .gpx

Tags: iphone, gps

Is there an iPhone app that allows one to follow an imported .gpx track, in a car navigation-like way?

The apps I found so far, like Trails, can only display the track on a map. What I am looking for is a "download-and-forget" experience for my bike trips. I want to import a track and just look at my iPhone to tell me in which direction is the next waypoint, or how can I get back on track if I get lost.

Comment: Have you checked the answers at [What is a good iPhone app for bikers?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/166/8)

Comment: I have, actually. I am aware that there is a plethora of GPS logging apps, and a number of apps can import a track and show it on the map. On the other hand, there are car navigation apps. I'm looking for something that can combine these functionalities.

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11309/iphone-app-to-follow-navigate-an-imported-gpx

Comment: .gpx files aren't required to contain waypoints.  If the .gpx file doesn't contain any waypoints, then it doesn't matter what app you import the .gpx file into, you'll never get any waypoint notifications telling you to turn.  It seems to me that you're asking for turn-by-turn navigation apps rather than apps that can import a .gpx file.

Comment: @rclocher3 Indeed I am. When I asked this question in 2011, I phrased it "in a car navigation-like way". Now "turn-by-turn" is the more frequently used description for this feature. Nevertheless, with intelligent apps such as Komoot, I can import any type of .gpx track or route and they will be converted into a perfectly good turn-by-turn navigation experience for the bike. I don't think it existed in 2011, but it certainly can be done now.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several years, many new options for on the bike, turn-by-turn navigation have appeared. These are some of them:

- [Komoot](https://komoot.com)
- [RideWithGPS](https://ridewithgps.com/)

Changing my accepted answer to this one, to reflect the current state of the art.

Comment: Appears you have to upgrade to the premium (and expensive) version of RideWithGps to use offline gpx files. Komoot seems to load them ok though

Answer (score 3):

http://www.motionx.com/ is the closest I've seen. You can set it's map to show track up as you ride. It doesn't know where the roads are though, nor zoom in or out depending on your speed, nor show upcoming turns.

**NOTE** As of 2019, this app is now end-of-lifed. It was great while it lasted.

Comment: While MotionX is not exactly what I was asking for, I have downloaded it and used it for over a year and I can confirm that it's an excellent app for cyclists (or anyone who navigates in a terrain). What's especially compelling about it is that it can download maps to local storage, in a dead easy way, so it's extremely useful during foreign trips, when downloading maps on-the-fly via 3G connection can be prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Co-Rider app can follow a GPX file from your dropbox account and it also integrates with Ride with GPS for easy access to your saved routes. You can also drop pins and get directions to random points as well.  Voice navigation is available, and I've found it useful.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/co-rider/id538095358?mt=8